# Building a chatbot using seq2seq with attention

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am building a chatbot using seq2seq + attention mechanism first I implemented with-out attention layer I got good results with accuracy 70% 
 Now I trying to increase my accuracy for that I added attention layer to my seq2seq encoder-decoder model 
 All this I'm implementing in Keras 
when I'm adding attention layer to my seq2seq model I'm getting index error: list index out of range

procedure what I follow

```
# encoder_input_data
tr_que = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(final_questions)
max_que_len = max([len(x) for x in tr_que])
que_pad = pad_sequences(tr_que, maxlen=max_que_len, padding='post')
encoder_input_data = np.array(que_pad)
print('Encoder input shape :',encoder_input_data.shape)

# decoder_input_data
tr_ans = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(final_answers)
max_ans_len = max([len(x) for x in tr_ans])
ans_pad = pad_sequences(tr_ans, maxlen=max_ans_len, padding='post' )
decoder_input_data = np.array(ans_pad)
print('Decoder input shape :',decoder_input_data.shape)

# decoder_output_data
tr_ans = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(final_answers)
for i in range(len(tr_ans)) :
    tr_ans[i] = tr_ans[i][1:]
ans_pad = pad_sequences(tr_ans, maxlen=max_ans_len, padding='post' )
cat_ans = keras.utils.to_categorical(ans_pad, vocab_size)
decoder_output_data = np.array(cat_ans)
print('Decoder output shape :',decoder_output_data.shape)

output :
Encoder input shape : (5806, 22)
Decoder input shape : (5806, 38)
Decoder output shape : (5806, 38, 5661)
```

Above code, a snippet is inputs and outputs to my seq2seq model 
Now from below reference link, a imported the attention layer 
https://towardsdatascience.com/light-on-math-ml-attention-with-keras-dc8dbc1fad39 
from the above reference, I'm trying to applied attention layer to my seq2seq model  like below

```
#Encoder inputs 
Embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 300, mask_zero=True)
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,), name='encoder_input_layer')
encoder_embedding = Embedding_layer(encoder_inputs)
encoder_outputs , state_h , state_c = LSTM(1024 , return_state=True, name='encoder_layer')(encoder_embedding)
# We discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c] 

# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs =  Input(shape=(None,), name='decoder_input_layer')
# We set up our decoder to return full output sequences,
# and to return internal states as well. We don't use the 
# return states in the training model, but we will use them in inference.
decoder_embedding = Embedding_layer(decoder_inputs)
decoder_lstm =  LSTM(1024, return_state=True, return_sequences=True, name='decoder_layer')
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_embedding, initial_state=encoder_states)

#Attention layer
#https://towardsdatascience.com/light-on-math-ml-attention-with-keras-dc8dbc1fad39
#Inputs to the attention layer are encoder_outputs and decoder_outputs
#we can get this pre-computed attention class "AttentionLayer" from above reference link 
attention_layer = AttentionLayer(name='attention_layer')
attention_output = attention_layer([encoder_outputs, decoder_outputs])

#Concatenate the attention_output and decoder_outputs as an input to the softmax layer.
attention_decoder_input = Concatenate(axis=-1, name='concat_layer')([decoder_outputs, attention_output])

#Dense layer
decoder_dense =  TimeDistributed(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax', name = 'softmax_layer'))

#decoder outputs 
#attention_decoder_input to the dense layer 
output = decoder_dense(attention_decoder_input)

# `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], output)
#compiling the model 
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
#model summary
model.summary()
```

After applying this I'm facing below error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-af4228e23d00> in <module>()
     19 #Inputs to the attention layer are encoder_outputs and decoder_outputs
     20 attention_layer = AttentionLayer(name='attention_layer')
---> 21 attention_output = attention_layer([encoder_outputs, decoder_outputs])
     22 
     23 #Concatenate the attention_output and decoder_outputs as an input to the softmax layer.

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    868           return self._dims[key].value
    869         else:
--> 870           return self._dims[key]
    871     else:
    872       if isinstance(key, slice):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

can anyone help me what is the mistake I did

Thanks in advance